# `forever`: How to forward information to next iteration?

Tags: loops, haskell, monads

There is a thread waiting for new input in a queue to safe it to the file system. It also creates backup copies. The [sscce](http://sscce.org/) looks like this:

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.STM
import Control.Monad
import Data.Time.Clock.POSIX

main :: IO ()
main = do
    contentQueue <- atomically $ newTQueue
    _ <- forkIO $ saveThreadFunc contentQueue
    forever $ do
        line <- getLine
        atomically $ writeTQueue contentQueue line

saveThreadFunc :: TQueue String -> IO ()
saveThreadFunc queue = forever $ do
    newLine <- atomically $ readTQueue queue
    now <- round `fmap` getPOSIXTime :: IO Int
    writeFile "content.txt" newLine
    -- todo: Backup no more than once every 86400 seconds (24 hours).
    backupContent now newLine

backupContent :: Int -> String -> IO ()
backupContent t = writeFile $ "content.backup." ++ show t
```

Now it would be great if the backup would not be written more than once every 24 hours. In imperative programming I would probably use a mutable `int lastBackupTime` inside the "forever loop" in `saveThreadFunc`. How can the same effect be achieved in Haskell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about `Control.Monad.Loops.iterateM_`?  This is slightly neater as it avoids explict recursion.

```
iterateM_ :: Monad m => (a -> m a) -> a -> m b

saveThreadFunc :: TQueue String -> Int -> IO ()
saveThreadFunc queue = iterateM_ $ \lastBackupTime -> do
  newLine <- atomically $ readTQueue queue
  now <- round `fmap` getPOSIXTime :: IO Int
  writeFile "content.txt" newLine
  let makeNewBackup = now >= lastBackupTime + 86400
  when makeNewBackup (backupContent now newLine)
  return (if makeNewBackup then now else lastBackupTime)
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `forever` with explicit recursion.

```
foo :: Int -> IO ()
foo n = do
  use n
  foo (n+1)
```

Of course, you can use any type for your state instead of `Int`.

Otherwise, if you *really* want the mutable state:

```
foo :: IO ()
foo = do
  r <- newIORef (0 :: Int) 
  forever $ do
        n <- readIORef r
        use n
        writeIORef r (n+1)
```

Unless you really need mutability for some other reason, I'd not recommend the second option.

---

Adapting the above idea to the concrete code:

```
saveThreadFunc :: Int -> TQueue String -> IO ()
saveThreadFunc lastBackupTime queue = do
  newLine <- atomically $ readTQueue queue
  now <- round `fmap` getPOSIXTime :: IO Int
  writeFile "content.txt" newLine
  let makeNewBackup = now >= lastBackupTime + 86400
  if makeNewBackup then do
    backupContent now newLine
    saveThreadFunc now queue 
   else 
    saveThreadFunc lastBackupTime queue
```

Comment: The version without mutable state looks cleaner to me. So in my example it would look this [this](https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/2db496f5ceecdf93820f), right?

Comment: @TobiasHermann: I don't think so.  That version never leaves `saveThreadFunc` and never reads a new input line.

Comment: @chi: As it is, the `forever` block is never executed.

Comment: @TomEllis `return ()` does not leave the function. It packs the empty tuple in a monadic context, to make it's type match the line above it. But your remark reminds me, that using `when` is nicer to read here: https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/27b6cb6932febd176c83. Edit: chi's current version seems even nicer to me. :)

Comment: @TobiasHermann Your code looks fine AFAICS. You way want to use `when` or to follow the approach I appended above. This is a very minor, and arguable, cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to add state to a monad is using `StateT` from `Control.Monad.Trans.State.Strict` in the `transformers` package (part of the Haskell Platform). In this case, you would change the type of `saveThreadFunc`:

```
saveThreadFunc :: TQueue String -> StateT Int IO ()
```

You'd have to `Control.Monad.Trans.lift` the actual `IO` things to `StateT Int IO`, and then in the end `evalStateT` to turn the whole thing into `IO a`.

This approach is perhaps more modular than the the `iterateM_` one Tom Ellis suggests (although that's something of a matter of taste), and will generally be optimized better than the `IORef` version chi suggests you avoid.